# add VMWare virtual machine to the domain

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtual-machine, windows-domain

How can I add VM to a desired domain. My Dev machine is connected to Domain1 but my VMWare VM is connected to WORKGROUP. When I try to connect it via Control Panel, Settings.. I get an error message saying that the computer name was created using a different account. Can only helpdesk add VM to Domain1? Is it even possible? Please help.. thanks..

Comment: Talk to your helpdesk.  AS it stands we would need  more info to assist and your support team could do this quickly and easily if it is OK to do so.

Comment: If they were competent and helpful.. I would not be asking here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a computer (either physical or a VM) to a domain you need rights on that domain.

Usually these rights are not granted to domain administrators, but they can be delegated to other groups. The people working at the helpdesk are likely one such group.

Thus:

1. Check which name your VM uses. If needed correct this to match the corporate naming scheme and reboot.
2. Call the helpdesk and ask them to add a computer with $this_name to the domain. They may want to log in on your computer to do this (Usually with an corporate account, which might not have been setup on your VM. If this is the case consider this step 0.)

Alternatively, ask if they can delegate these right to you. To do that they need to:

1. Open the Default Domain Group policy.
2. Navigate through Computer configuration / Windows settings / Security settings / Local policies to **User rights assignment**.
3. Expand this and double-click 'Add workstations to domain'
4. Check the Define these policy settings box.
5. Press the [Add user or group] button and complete the dialog to add the user or group.
6. [Apply] and [OK].

Or:, delegate rights using Active Directory Users and Computers:

1. Open the Active Directory Users and Computers snap-in.
2. Right-click the container under which you want the computers added, and press Delegate Control.
3. Press [Next]. [Add] (and add)
4. After adding all the users and/or groups, press [next].
5. Select create custom task to delegate and press [next].
6. Select Only the following objects in the folder, check Computer objects, check the Create selected objects in this folder box, and press next.
7. Check the Create all child object box and press [next] and [finish]

Answer (score 0):

Helpdesk has special priviliges and they were able to add the VM to the domain via control panel.